# How can you code the C "&&" operator in x86?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

How can I code the C '&&' operator in x86?  For example:

```
int a = ...
int b = ...
int c = a && b;
```

What would be the equivalent of the last line in x86?

EDIT: I want to do the above without any jumps.

EDIT: g++ generates this, but I don't understand it:

```
testl   %edi, %edi
setne   %dl
xorl    %eax, %eax
testl   %esi, %esi
setne   %al
andl    %edx, %eax
```

Comment: There are no jumps required for that example; the code in question has a very direct translation to assembly. @Ivan has your answer for you already.

Comment: An easy way would be to compile a simple program with these lines using `g++ -S file.cpp`. Alternatively, you can compile it in Visual Studio with assembly output. Both should give you the few lines of code to accomplish this.

Comment: I tried that, but the gcc output didn't make any sense (see above)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how GCC implements it at `-O3`.

```
    movl    8(%esp), %edx  ;; load argument into edx
    xorl    %eax, %eax     ;; eax = 0
    movl    4(%esp), %ecx  ;; load other argument into ecx
    testl   %edx, %edx     ;; Is EDX nonzero?
    setne   %al            ;; al = 1 if Z = 0
    xorl    %edx, %edx     ;; EDX = 0
    testl   %ecx, %ecx     ;; Is ECX nonzero?
    setne   %dl            ;; dc = 1 if Z = 0
    andl    %edx, %eax     ;; edx &= eax
```

Note that this code does not short-circuit; this is because in this case GCC can prove that there are no side effects from the second argument. If the second argument has side-effects, you must implement it using jumps. For example:

```
int test(int *a, int *b) {
  return (*a)++ && (*b)++;
}
```

becomes:

```
test:
        pushl   %ebx            ;; save ebx
        movl    8(%esp), %eax   ;; load a into eax
        movl    12(%esp), %ecx  ;; load b in to ecx
        movl    (%eax), %edx    ;; *a -> edx
        leal    1(%edx), %ebx   ;; ebx = edx + 1
        movl    %ebx, (%eax)    ;; *a <- ebx
        xorl    %eax, %eax      ;; eax = 0
        testl   %edx, %edx      ;; if the old value of *a was 0...
        je      .L2             ;; jump to the end
        movl    (%ecx), %eax    ;; *a -> eax
        testl   %eax, %eax      ;; does *a = 0?
        leal    1(%eax), %edx   ;; edx = *a + 1 (does not set flags!)
        setne   %al             ;; al = 1 if Z (ie, if a = 0 at the testl above)
        movl    %edx, (%ecx)    ;; save edx to *a (increment *a)
        movzbl  %al, %eax       ;; zero-extend al to eax
.L2:
        popl    %ebx            ;; restore ebx
        ret                     ;; return
```

Comment: Is there any way for you to reduce the above code to what is needed?  Last time I checked (for example), NASM didn't have .cfi_startproc

Comment: Just remove the cfi junk. It's only used for high-level debugging and C++ exception handling.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it without jumps because && is a short-circuit operator.

```
    XOR ecx, ecx
    MOV eax, <value of A>
    MOV ebx, <value of B>
    TEST eax, eax
    JZ testDone
    TEST ebx, ebx
    JZ testDone
    INC ecx
testDone:
    ...
```

Comment: Nice, excellent point.  However, how would you do it if && was not short-circuited?  i.e., if I had 2 registers, eax and ebx, and wanted to put the logical AND into ecx.

Comment: If the second argument has no side-effects (or you don't care about short-circuiting), you can avoid jumps on x86 (see my answer for an example)

Comment: @DigitalRoss, assuming the right-hand-side is side-effect-free, yes

Comment: @bdonian, agreed. Even without side effects C99 seems to prohibit evaluating the second operand *at all* and so I don't think it's really possible on any architecture to avoid a branch.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the obvious implementation uses branches. My original idea was to convert each operand into either 0 or -1 via a sign-extending bit shift, and then using the bitwise and instruction, but [gcc(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) has reminded me of the *set<sub>xy</sub>* x86 instruction, so that seems easier.

The following function implements: `int f(int a, int b) { return a && b; }`

```
.text
.globl f
f:
  cmpl   $0, 4(%esp)
  setne  %dl
  cmpl   $0, 8(%esp)
  setne  %al
  movzbl %al, %eax
  andl   %edx, %eax
  ret
```

As it happens, the correct *value* for the expression can be computed without branches or jumps, but by defining my implementation as a function I'm kind of cheating because it forces both operands to be evaluated in order to make the function call, at which point the function does no harm by *reading* both operands without the short-circuit because the parameters are known to be copies.

But for open code, whether this can be done without a jump depends entirely on whether the right-hand operand can be evaluated without side-effects. So, it depends on the type. Imagine the case where the right hand operand is a function call, perhaps an I/O op or a kernel system call. The generated code cannot evaluate it *at all* if the left hand operand is false, and I don't see how that could be done without a branch or jump.

It's interesting that gcc -O (which generates similar code) seems to violate C99 6.5.13(4) which states flatly *"If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated."*  In the case of assembling *f()* it apparently decides that since a value parameter can't have side effects, then there is no harm in compiling code contrary to C99's literal specification.

Comment: Very nice.  I didn't know about the set[XY] family of functions.  My knowledge of assembly is admittedly rather limited.  ^_^  Now if only x86 assembly didn't have so many instructions...  LOL.  Thanks for the lesson.  :)

Comment: compl doesn't seem to work with a literal; the answer you had before with test worked though.

Comment: This only works if the operands have no side effects. If there are side effects you must perform separate conditional jumps for each.

Comment: Matt, if you have a literal you don't need to test it -- you know if it's true or false.  Or you can assign the literal to a reg for the cmpl.

Comment: @R, good point, it's only possible to compute the same *value* without a branch so I've updated my answer to reference the side-effect problem.

Answer (score -1):

This will work (and is the fastest piece of code) **only if** *a* and *b* variables are normalized, i.e. it contains a boolean value 1 to mark true or 0 to mark false.

```
MOV eax, <value>  ; a = ...
MOV ebx, <value>  ; b = ...
MOV ecx, eax
AND ecx, ebx      ; c = a & b
```

Comment: Did you mean `xor ecx, ecx` on the third line?

Comment: Ehh... note that this may fail if `a` and `b` aren't boolean values. @Mike: Probably meant `MOV ecx, eax`; otherwise, the first line is a dead store.

Comment: a and b can be arbitrary integers.

Comment: What does MOV ecx, ecx do?  And isn't the AND instruction a bitwise and?

Comment: Yes, AND is a bitwise instruction, but eax and ebx are values loaded directly, not pointers. If you have your variables in memory, you have to do something like MOV eax, [var_a]

Comment: Wait, what if eax = 01 and ebx = 10?  Then ecx = 0 at the end of all this, which is not what I want.  In C, if you do 01 && 10, the result is non-zero.

Comment: Bitwise AND doesn't do the job of &&.

Comment: I've edited the comment on the last line of code to at least accurately state what it's doing.